# How to push two different images with different tags to a single GitHub repository?

Tags: docker, github, ghcr

Let's say I have built two docker images on my local machine. One for .NET and one for React. Since they are different images, of course they can't both have the same tag. Let' say I have tagged them:

```
ghcr.io/project/api

ghcr.io/project/front
```

And let's say my repository address is `github.com/username/repo`.

And I have also logged into GHCR using this shell command, and my user name and PAT:

```
docker login ghcr.io
```

How can I push those images to that repo?

If I simply execute `docker push ghcr.io/project/api` it throws an error. The same is true for `docker push ghcr.io/project/front`. The only command that works is `docker push ghcr.io/username/repo`. However, I can't tag both images the same tag.

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70693637/how-to-push-a-docker-image-to-github-container-repository-when-the-name-does-no), it's mentinoned that it's possible to push many images to one github repo. But I'm stuck at how and there was no answer and I can't find anything in GitHub documentation either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Keep "docker image" and "github repository" separate in your head, because they're very different things. ghcr.io registers and holds docker images, not Git (or GitHub) repositories. They're run by the same *organization* (i.e., GitHub) but they use different procedures. See https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry for GitHub's instructions for using ghcr.io.

Comment: Note that "docker push" sends docker images (not Git repositories) to docker hosting sites (ghcr.io in this case), not to Git-repository hosting sites (github.com). As for the note that "However, I can't tag both images the same tag": this is to be expected. The docker image tag is a name for a hash ID. Two different hash IDs require two different names.

Comment: @torek, maybe I can't express myself clearly. I know all the things you said. But I encounter error when I want to push `ghcr.io/x/y` and `ghcr.io/a/b` in the actions that belong to the repository `github.com/alpha/beta`. I really don't know how to say it in any other way. Is it not clear? Inside the actions of `github.com/alpha/beta` I can only push an image that is tagged `ghcr.io/alpha/beta`. I read that link you sent and they don't address this.

Comment: Did you mean to ask then about having a *GitHub action* that runs `docker push`? That would be a question for the [tag:github-actions] tag and you should say that explicitly. The descriptions on the page I linked are for manual, human-driven `docker push` commands, not for automation via GitHub's CI/CD system. (Still, the automated ones would presumably be very similar, they just need a way to authenticate to ghcr.io. You'll need a GitHub-actions expert to say how to do that.)